# convert 0.5 to 0.50 in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string which holds 0.5. I have to convert in to 0.50.

I have tried following ways but nothing works.Please help

hdnSliderValue.Value is 0.5,I want workFlow.QualityThresholdScore to be 0.50

```
workFlow.QualityThresholdScore = Convert.ToDecimal(String.format("{0:d}",hdnSliderValue.Value));

workFlow.QualityThresholdScore = Convert.ToDecimal(String.format("{0:0.00}",hdnSliderValue.Value));
```

IS there any built in function or will i have to do string handling to accomplish this.

Comment: And the target `workFlow.QualityThresholdScore` is a decimal type, right? Your problem is probably when you _show_ that, not when you _assign_ it.

Comment: How can I do the same in Javascript and NodeJS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way probably *is* to use string conversions:

```
string text = "0.5";
decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(text);
string reformatted = parsed.ToString("0.00");
decimal reparsed = decimal.Parse(reformatted);

Console.WriteLine(reparsed); // Prints 0.50
```

That's pretty ugly though :(

You certainly *could* do it by first parsing the original string, then messing around with the internal format of the decimal - but it would be significantly harder.

EDIT: Okay, in case it's an i18n issue, here's a console app which should *definitely* print out 0.50:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo invariant = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        string text = "0.5";
        decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(text, invariant);
        string reformatted = parsed.ToString("0.00", invariant);
        decimal reparsed = decimal.Parse(reformatted, invariant);

        Console.WriteLine(reparsed.ToString(invariant)); // Prints 0.50
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir,as per your code i am doing this,      

       decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(hdnSliderValue.Value);
        string reformatted = parsed.ToString("0.00");
        workFlow.QualityThresholdScore = decimal.Parse(reformatted);

still workFlow.QualityThresholdScore holds 0.5. Quick watch for decimal.Parse(reformatted) also shows 0.5. Please tell how to rectify this.

Comment: @Rohit: This could just be the debugger causing a problem. What happens if you use `Console.WriteLine(workFlow.QualityThresholdScore)`? The code I've shown works... Also, what is the code for the QualityThresholdScore property? If you assign 0.50m to it directly, how does that show up?

Comment: I tried pasting your code in a console application and it still prints 0.5. Is there any globalization setting which is making it to print 0.5.

Comment: public Nullable<decimal> QualityThresholdScore { get; set; }

If I do 

workFlow.QualityThresholdScore = 0.50m;

it still shows 0.5

Comment: @Rohit: That suggests there's something wrong with how you're showing it, rather than the property itself. It *could* be a globalization thing, but I'm still somewhat surprised... I'll update the snippet with a culture-insensitive version.

Comment: How can I do the same in Javascript and NodeJS?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati You should look for similar questions with the appropriate tags, and ask them if they don't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

It's `ToString("N2")`.

Edit: Add test code to show how it works

```
decimal a = 0.5m;
Console.WriteLine(a);
// prints out 0.5
string s = a.ToString("N2");
decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(s);
// prints out 0.50
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: i don't think this method will help to convert 0.5 to 0.50

Comment: @Danny Chen: Works for me, I'll amend the answer with the code I used to test it.

Comment: @ho1: That's starting off with a decimal - the OP is starting off with a string, according to the question. Admittedly it's not terribly clear - it could just be badly described.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, got mixed up with the question and sample code (I thought `hdnSliderValue.Value` looked like it'd be a double or decimal or something).

Comment: I'd suggest that as the OP has tagged and written the question in C# any answers should also be.

Comment: @David Neale: Not sure if much point since my answer is probably not answering the question, but changed over since in general I agree (though I'd be slightly worried about any C# developer that had to think for more than a few seconds to decode that code :)).

Comment: @ho1. Fair enough in this circumstance. It was more of a general pedantic comment :)

Answer (score 0):

In numerics, 0.5 == 0.50. A zero doesn't add any information, so if QualityThresholdScore is of a numeric type, you will get 0.5 no matter what. If it is a string, use `decimal.ToString("0.00");`.

Comment: Not true: `decimal` keeps track of trailing zeroes.

Comment: How do you know what the OP's use case considers to be important? It may wish to differentiate between 0.5 and 0.50 for some reason; after all, that ability is precisely why decimal *does* keep track of trailing zeroes.

Comment: While true from a mathematical standpoint values of type `Decimal` are not normalized. Therefore 0.5 and 0.50 actually have two different representations using `Decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
workFlow.QualityThresholdScore = Convert.ToDecimal(hdnSliderValue.Value.ToString("N2"));

Answer (score 0):

Stringy version since no-one has suggested it.

```
      string pointFive = "0.5";
      int decimals = (pointFive.Length-1) - pointFive.IndexOf('.');
      if (decimals >= pointFive.Length)
        pointFive += ".00";
      else if (decimals == 1)
        pointFive += "0";
      else if (decimals == 0)
        pointFive += "00";
```

Might even be quicker than numeric conversions and formatting functions.